# How to style a UL/LI drop down

Tags: html, css

I have a unordered list which I am trying to customize during runtime that is invoked by DropKick CSS styling.

Here is an image of what I see:

[image]

I tried to style it like this which didn't do anything to the style:

```
  .dk_options ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .dk_options_inner ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
```

When the style originally had the following, it worked like a charm but interfered with my other HTML tags:

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

I am trying to apply that JUST to the dropdown only. How come my style isn't working? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Try adding `list-style-position:inside` - it shouldn't make a difference, but it might.

Comment: You are right, didn't do anything :/

Comment: `.dk_options_inner ul li a` should be `.dk_options_inner li a`, as   `.dk_options_inner` IS the `ul`.

Comment: Ah, hold on, you seem to be applying `list-style-type` to your `<a>` elements! Remove `a` from the CSS selectors. And what sphanley said.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge please provide fiddle to hunt bug

Comment: It will be hard to provide fiddle, as it makes use of many third party libraries :/

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I went into the JS file itself which is auto assigning the list-style as well as the padding and modified it and everything is working now. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear margin and padding from your list elements (ul).

```
.dk_options ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

if you want to clear margin and padding only for first level menu, you have to select it like this:

```
.dk_options > ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

or if you want to clear margin and padding from sub-level elements, you can select like this:

```
.dk_options > ul > li ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Yes it should. These options are for clearing margin and the padding from ul elements.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I went into the JS file itself which is auto assigning the list-style as well as the padding and modified it and everything is working now. Thanks for the help, I will UP VOTE and ACCEPT because you took the time.

Comment: I'm glad if i can help. Search google for css selectors for more information.